# AWS IoT Rule Query Statement for the Array JSON payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

How to use AWS IoT Rule Query Statement to get temperature and humidity from the following MQTT payload to 'example' topic?

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-08-26T14:21:46Z",
    "type": "Gateway",
    "mac": "XXYYZZXXYYZZ",
    "gatewayFree": 96,
    "gatewayLoad": 0.26
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-08-26T14:21:46Z",
    "type": "S1",
    "mac": "XXYYZZXXYYXX",
    "bleName": "",
    "rssi": -53,
    "battery": 100,
    "temperature": 0.69,
    "humidity": 37.28
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2019-08-26T14:21:46Z",
    "type": "iBeacon",
    "mac": "XXYYZZXXYYYY",
    "bleName": "",
    "ibeaconUuid": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
    "ibeaconMajor": 0,
    "ibeaconMinor": 0,
    "rssi": -64,
    "ibeaconTxPower": -59,
    "battery": 0
  }
]
```

So far, I cannot find it on [AWS IoT SQL Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it's working!

```
SELECT (SELECT temperature, humidity from input) as output FROM 'iot/topic'
```

I have modified the input JSON to have a **key** -- see below.

Here is the modified input:

```
{
   "input": [ ... your json array elements ... ]
}
```

Here is the output:

```
{
  "output": [
    {},
    {
      "temperature": 0.69,
      "humidity": 37.28
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

cheers,
ram

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one...

```
{
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM 'iot/example' WHERE mac = 'XXYYZZXXYYXX'",
    ...
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you have SQL query of `SELECT * FROM example/topic/name`, the array will be read into a variable named `$unknown`. You can easily see this if you configured a rule action to send your data to `CloudWatch`.
So if you are triggering a `Lambda`, then you can access array data as below. (nodeJs code snippet)

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const arrayData = event['$unknown'];
    # process your data
};
```